# Simple OOP query. Python: saving object names in __init__

Tags: python, oop

As close to the title as possible.  I am very new to OOP (and coding in general) and would like to create a program that plays Blackjack.  I want to save the objects I create into a list automatically so once it's created I can use the list to cycle through them (I want to create player objects, but save the variable names (right word???) to a list so once it's created using user input I can automatically access them.

So far I've built this:

```
ROSTER = []   

class Player():
"""player in the game"""

    def __init__(self, name, score= 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        ROSTER.append(self.name)
```

But of course this only gives me the names put into the variable self.name... how can I capture the variable names (right term once again?).  self.name won't (afaik) let me access the individual objects via:

excuse the crap formatting plz. =/

Also, if I'm using the wrong terms plz correct me.  Learning on your own is kinda hard as far as mastering all the terms.

EDIT: sorry, my post was confusing.  The code I posted was meant to show a dead end, not what I am looking for, and my terminology is pretty bad (I feel like a foreigner most of the time).  When I said variable names, I think I should have said 'object names' (?) so:

p1 = Player("bob")

p2 = Player("sue")

I want ["p1","p2"] (or if a string format will give me problems when I try to call them, whatever the appropriate way is.)

Once again, sorry for the super confusing first post.  Hopefully this edit is a little clearer and more focused.

Comment: What are "the names put into the variable self.name" and what are "the variable names"?

Comment: do you wanna access them while iterating over the list?

Comment: You should avoid the global variable usage. Just pass the list as parameter: `player1 = Player(roster, name='Name', score=score)`, and in `__init__`:`...roster.append(self)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put `self` in the roster instead. I.e.:

```
ROSTER = []

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, score = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        ROSTER.append(self)
```

Then you would use the `ROSTER` list like this:

```
>>> p1 = Player("Jane")
>>> p2 = Player("John")
>>> ROSTER
[<__main__.Player instance at 0x10a937a70>, <__main__.Player instance at 0x10a937a28>]
>>> for p in ROSTER:
...   print p.name, p.score
... 
Jane 0
John 0
```

Or, perhaps better, you could make ROSTER a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
ROSTER = dict()

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, score = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        ROSTER[self.name] = self
```

That way you can access the player objects by name using `ROSTER[name]`, and you can cycle through them with `ROSTER.values()`. For example:

```
>>> p1 = Player("Jane")
>>> p2 = Player("John")
>>> print ROSTER["Jane"].name, ROSTER["Jane"].score
Jane 0
>>> print ROSTER["John"].name, ROSTER["John"].score
John 0
>>> for p in ROSTER.values():
...   print p.name, p.score
... 
Jane 0
John 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this?

```
ROSTER = []   

class Player():

    def __init__(self, name, score= 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        ROSTER.append(self)

a=Player('Jack',100)
b=Player('Blackk',1000)
c=Player('Mike')

for x in ROSTER:
    print(x.name,x.score)
```

**output:**

```
Jack 100
Blackk 1000
Mike 0
```